# UVs distort when loading image in UV editor

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I have unwrapped UVs that I want to match to an image but whenever I load an image it distorts. Is this a bug?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the canvas size so your image becomes square then import it into the image editor? powers of 2 are usually preferred 256, 512, 1024, 2048,...etc.)?

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla Of course this helps but it increases the file size unnecessarily. Imagine you have an image texture of let's say a line of text which is very wide but not very high. Making this square blows up the file size extraordinarily.

Comment: You can pack all your textures in a square sized file, that way you load a smaller number of files, otherwise you will have to redo the unwrapping. My workflow is to model, unwrap and pack UVs, export UVs to image editing program, then compose and optimize textures.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's by design.

UV coordinates are relative to image dimensions. So then you put an image with different aspect ratio, it distorts. But you are able to use different size variations of texture (for example 512x512, 1024x1024, 4096x4096, etc.), without changing UV.

To fix your issue, you can redo UV set by selecting the orthogonal view and pressing <kbd>U</kbd> ⇾ Project From View

Comment: Can this not be avoided? How am I supposed to texture the keyboard if it's distorted like this

Comment: If you are working with texture with non-square aspect ratio, plug it to the material before making the UV. In that case, all operations with UV will be operated according to the  aspect ratio

Comment: @Crantisz I would add this comment to your answer - although it is by design to stretch the UVs according to the image aspect ratio for several reasons, your comment is what actually helps him to get what he wants in this case because the advantages of the standard UV behavior are not needed here I guess.